# CASE WHEN in Hibernate @OrderBy annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Is it possible to use `CASE WHEN ... END` or even native SQL in the Hibernate @OrderBy annotation? How?

E.g. (the `Child` Object has a `type` property):

```
@OneToMany
@OrderBy("CASE WHEN type='GIRL' THEN 1 WHEN type='BOY' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END ASC")
private List<Child> children;
```

Comment: The JPA spec still doesn't allow this. Feature just added here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/301

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@OrderBy` annotation is actually a JPA annotation, which accepts a comma separated list of field names on an entity to order by.  The order is performed only upon the initial query to the database and will not be maintained if the list is modified.  So in short, no you cannot provide pure SQL to the `@OrderBy` annotation.

One work around is to create a view with an additional column that contains the result of your case statement.  For example:

```
create or replace view V_CHILD as
   select
   NAME VARCHAR2,
   TYPE VARCHAR2,
   CASE WHEN type='GIRL' THEN 1 WHEN type='BOY' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END as TYPE_ORDER
   from CHILD;
```

Then map an entity to the view exactly as you would for a table.  The entity will contain a `typeOrder` field which can be specified in the `@OrderBy` annotation.  Just be aware that you cannot insert or update the entity since it is based off of a view.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of this approach. Just implemented it and worked without any bigger problems.

Comment: @mkurz Glad I could help.  I use the view approach often when the JPQL would get out of hand.  It has worked really well for me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

`org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy` takes native sql not like `javax.persistence.OrderBy` that takes JPQL as mentioned at hibernate docs.

> Order a collection using SQL ordering (not HQL ordering).
> Different from {@link javax.persistence.OrderBy} in that this expects SQL fragment, JPA OrderBy expects a valid JPQL order-by fragment.